# How to store distances of nodes from root in breadth-first tree?

Tags: python, tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Let `G(V,E)` be an undirected graph. I want create a breadth-first tree from `G` storing nodes with corresponding distances from root. please help.

```
import networkx as nx

g=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(12,.1)
visited = [] 
queue = []     
tree={}
def bfs(visited, g, node):
  visited.append(node)
  queue.append(node)

  while queue:
    s = queue.pop(0)
    tree[s]=[]
    for neighbour in list(g.adj[s]):
      if neighbour not in visited:
        visited.append(neighbour)
        tree[s].append(neighbour)
        queue.append(neighbour)

bfs(visited, g, 1)
print(tree)
```

Comment: please describe the output you get from above implementation and the output you expect.

Comment: I want a BFS tree for a root node storing distance to all the vertices in the graph. I have tried to create a breadth-first tree from a graph and now how can i store distance in it?

Comment: if you build tree then you should also count distance in the same code. Probably before every `for`-loop you would need `distance += 1` - and you have to add this to tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep every item as `(node, distance)` and append `(neighbour, distance+1)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

# --- functions ---

def bfs(g, node):
    distance = 0
    visited = [node]
    queue = [(node, distance)]

    tree = {}

    while queue:
        s, distance = queue.pop(0)
        tree[s] = []
        for neighbour in list(g.adj[s]):
            if neighbour not in visited:
                visited.append(neighbour)
                tree[s].append((neighbour, distance+1))
                queue.append((neighbour, distance+1))

    return tree
  
# --- main ---

#G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(12, .1)
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(([1,2],[2,3], [2,4], [3, 5], [4,5]))

tree = bfs(G, 1)
print(tree)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Result (manually reformated):

```
{
  1: [(2, 1)], 
  2: [(3, 2), (4, 2)], 
  3: [(5, 3)], 
  4: [], 
  5: []
}
```

For graph

[image]

---

Evenutally you can even use `tree[(s, distance)]`

```
def bfs(g, node):
    distance = 0
    visited = [node]
    queue = [(node, distance)]

    tree = {}

    while queue:
        s, distance = queue.pop(0)
        tree[(s, distance)] = []
        for neighbour in list(g.adj[s]):
            if neighbour not in visited:
                visited.append(neighbour)
                tree[(s, distance)].append((neighbour, distance+1))
                queue.append((neighbour, distance+1))

    return tree
```

Result (manually reformated):

```
{
  (1, 0): [(2, 1)], 
  (2, 1): [(3, 2), (4, 2)], 
  (3, 2): [(5, 3)], 
  (4, 2): [], 
  (5, 3): []
}
```

---

**BTW:**

I was thinking to use `json.dumps(tree, indent=2)` to reformat result automatically but it can't convert `node` to `json`.

But `pretty printer` can format it in similar way

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(tree, indent=2)
```

Result:

```
{ (1, 0): [(2, 1)],
  (2, 1): [(3, 2), (4, 2)],
  (3, 2): [(5, 3)],
  (4, 2): [],
  (5, 3): []}
```